# Recognizing center key on numeric keypad (with numlock off) with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard-events

I have the following function (in Qt 4)

```
void keyReleaseEvent( QKeyEvent *e )
{
   // recognize that 'r' is pressed
   if ( e->key() == Qt::Key_R )
   {
      doSomethingCool();
   }
}
```

I want to also recognize when the center key on the numeric keypad is pressed (the 5 key, but with numlock off).  I don't know what this key is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct key is `Qt::Key_Clear`.  I tried this earlier (as seen in previous edits), but I must have had numlock on, or had something else wrong.

Comment: +1, I wish more people would do this sort of thing when they have questions that are hard to figure out!